# JQ: print dictionary key names in correct order together with enclosed attributes

Tags: json, key, jq

I'm trying to use jq to extract the toplevel Attribute names together with the enclosed timestamps.

json input:

```
[
  {
    "Something": {
      "_metadata": {
        "timestamp": "2016-02-18T12:32:50.276Z"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "OtherThing": {
      "_metadata": {
        "timestamp": "2016-03-18T12:32:50.276Z"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "ThirdThing": {
      "_metadata": {
        "timestamp": "2016-04-18T12:32:50.276Z"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

desired output:

```
[
  {
    "Something": "2016-02-18T12:32:50.276Z"
  },
  {
    "OtherThing": "2016-03-18T12:32:50.276Z"
  },
  {
    "ThirdThing": "2016-04-18T12:32:50.276Z"
  }
]
```

Tried `jq '.[] | keys'` which gives me only the toplevel dictionary names.

```
[
  "Something"
]
[
  "OtherThing"
]
[
  "ThirdThing"
]
```

Which filter would achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a filter which uses [map_values](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) to produce the specified output:

```
map( map_values(._metadata.timestamp) )
```

Sample Run (assuming data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -M 'map( map_values(._metadata.timestamp) )' data.json
[
  {
    "Something": "2016-02-18T12:32:50.276Z"
  },
  {
    "OtherThing": "2016-03-18T12:32:50.276Z"
  },
  {
    "ThirdThing": "2016-04-18T12:32:50.276Z"
  }
]
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##pY29DoIwFIV3nqLpBIklUBQNL@Egk8aQJjRSQ3@EVgfl1a13QHT0Z7gnOV9O7nc8@V2A0BUOIbzRkttGqAMuRgSwAsZqZtkbBGyF5L1l0gDGNElzklCSrsqUFhktFklMl/kWj/sheOYwe@nWtuFd@bsv@9IHqq7@wzf/xBfsb14yEyKI6sxax/swnhzx9DZCkfd3bazQqveEKNe2RCjjLJSOXYh2FsoD)